# How to EDTWRD on Rational Developer for IBM i

Tags: rational-developer-for-i

I am working on an assignment for my iSeries file and design course. We have to edit the Zip Code field and Home Phone field to EDTWRD and I do not have the same options I had for the previous field showing me the options for Editing. I tried editing the source code but it does not allow me to insert a new line. My instructor is traveling and asked me to google my questions. My textbook is not up to date with the software.

[image: Here is a comparison of the field I can edit and the one's I am trying to edit]

Comment: It looks like your ZipCode properties is opened on a text constant rather than a field. Can you make sure you are prompting the right thing?

Comment: Thank you! I did find that was the issue!